# Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 39 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql

Me trabe con este error al empezar a crear mi cubo dimensional a la hora de insertar datos de una bd a otra bd
todos se insertan normal el error es cuando intento insertar a la tabla FacVenta

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 39
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__FacVenta__C6F4FC51C4DAB3BD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FacVenta2'. The duplicate key value is (10248).
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
create database DWFINAL

USE DWFINAL

CREATE TABLE DimEmpleado
(
    CodEmp int primary key,
    NomEmp varchar(26)
)

CREATE TABLE DimProducto
(
    CodPro int primary key,
    CodCat int references DimCategoria
    NomPro varchar (130),
    PrePro money
)

CREATE TABLE DimCategoria
(
    CodCat int primary key,
    NomCat  varchar(40)
)


CREATE TABLE DimClientes
(
    CodCli varchar(7) primary key,
    Empr    varchar(60),
    CiuCli  varchar(75),
    RegCli  varchar(23),
)

CREATE TABLE DimTiempo
(
    CodDimTie int primary key,
    FecTie date, --fecha
    AnnTie int,  --año
    MesTie int,  --mes
    NomMes varchar(10), -- nombre del mes
    DiaTie int, --dia
    NmDiaTie varchar(9) --nombre del dia
)

CREATE TABLE FacVenta2
(
    CodVen int primary key ,
    CodPro int references DimProducto,
    CodEmp int references DimEmpleado ,
    CodCli varchar(7) references DimClientes,
    CodDimTie int references DimTiempo ,
    ImpVen money
)
```

--Origen

```
insert DWFINAL.dbo.DimEmpleado
select CodEmp,Nombre+''+Apellido
from Empleados



insert DWFINAL.dbo.DimCategoria
select CodCat,NombreCategoria
from Categorias


insert DWFINAL.dbo.DimProducto
select CodPro,CodCat,ProductName,PrecioUnitario
from Productos

insert DWFINAL.dbo.DimClientes
select CodCli,Empresa,Ciudad,Region
from Clientes


insert DWFINAL.dbo.DimTiempo
select distinct
year(FechaVenta)*10000+month(FechaVenta)*100+Day(FechaVenta),
FechaVenta,
year(FechaVenta),
month(FechaVenta),
datename(month,FechaVenta),
day(FechaVenta),
datename(weekday,FechaVenta)
from Venta


insert DWFINAL.dbo.FacVenta2
select VentaDetalle.CodVen,CodPro
CodEmp,
CodCli,
year(FechaVenta)*10000+month(FechaVenta)*100+Day(FechaVenta),
sum(PrecioUnitario*Cantidad)--calculo
from Venta
inner join VentaDetalle
on Venta.CodVen=VentaDetalle.CodVen
group by VentaDetalle.CodVen,CodPro,CodEmp,CodCli,
year(FechaVenta)*10000+month(FechaVenta)*100+Day(FechaVenta)
```

Comment: En el último `INSERT` estarías agregando un valor duplicado para la llave primaria de la tabla, la cual no puede tener valores repetidos. El valor que intentas agregar es `10248`

Comment: como lo arreglo

Comment: Verificando que la clave  primaria no existe antes de insertarla.

Answer (score 0):

El diseño de tu llave primaria está incorrecto. Al hacer el siguiente insert estás insertando multiples filas con el mismo codventa.

```
insert DWFINAL.dbo.FacVenta2
select VentaDetalle.CodVen,CodPro
CodEmp,
CodCli,
year(FechaVenta)*10000+month(FechaVenta)*100+Day(FechaVenta),
sum(PrecioUnitario*Cantidad)--calculo
from Venta
inner join VentaDetalle
on Venta.CodVen=VentaDetalle.CodVen
group by VentaDetalle.CodVen,CodPro,CodEmp,CodCli,
year(FechaVenta)*10000+month(FechaVenta)*100+Day(FechaVenta)
```

Lo que necesitas, es cambiar la definición de la llave primaria por un conjunto de columnas que formen combinaciones que no se repitan. Podría ser CodVen y CodPro, pero no sé si un producto pueda tener dos filas en la misma venta.